# Problema ao compilar apk no flutter - R8: Program type already present

Tags: android, flutter, webview

Estou tentando compilar o apk para flutter, porém estou obtendo erro no r8, eu já tenho outros apps em flutter nunca tive problema para compilar, fazendo os teste percebir que o problema está sendo a biblioteca de webview, quando eu removo ela do pubspec o app compila como uma maravilha, porém eu não posso descartar o uso da webview no momento, ela é importante para o app, o estranho é que eu consigo depurar o app no dispositivo.

Eu já tentei várias soluções como estas abaixo:
 gradlew clean em projeto-flutter/android
 flutter clean
atualização pra ultima versão de dependencia do webview no pub spec.
já mudei pro canal master do flutter e também executei flutter upgrade mas nada resolve o problema.

segue o erro:

```
R8: Program type already present: io.flutter.plugins.webviewflutter.BuildConfig

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.


* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithR8ForRelease'.
> com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete
```

Comment: Tentou as propostas listadas nessa issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/40830 ?

Comment: Esse ai foi um dos primeiros que fiz.

Answer (score 1):

Tenta abrir seu projeto no andorid studio, so a parte do java mesmo, ve se precisa atualizar alguma biblioteca, se precisa atualizar alguma versao de algum dos plugins, se todos os plugins estao em conformidade com a versao do flutter.

Comment: então eu estou usando o intelij já fiz pub get, flutter upgrade mas nada resolve, outra observação é, eu revisei a maioria das bibliotecas e conferi no pubspeck uma por uma para ver se saiu versão nova

Comment: pelo android studio ele mostra cada plugin e a versao recomendada para cada uma de acordo com o  gradle e com o flutter

Comment: então fiz como vc disse mas não vi nada de diferente, continua com mesmo erro, lá no pubspeck não avisa nada, e há não sei se vc usou intelij mas intelij é praticamente o android studio a diferença é que é mais limpo por ser uma IDE pra várias outras linguagens.

Comment: Não, nunca usei ele. Então não sei o que pode ser.